Save draft via front end form
I'm trying to build a front end form which creates entries. So far, this works great when using actionInput('entries/save-entry').
I also want to provide the option to save the entry as a draft. I found, that I need to change the actionInput to actionInput('entry-revisions/save-draft').
Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It gives me a 404 error:

HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException Unable to
resolve the request "entry-revisions/save-draft".
in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php at line 561

I assume it changed with Craft Version 5, but I can't find any hints what needs to be changed for this to work.
I found the "Controller Actions" page in the docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/reference/controller-actions.html
This let me to the Class Reference for Entry Controllers: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v5/craft-controllers-entriescontroller.html#public-methods
Looking (and searching) through several pages there, I couldn't find any hints about how to save a draft.
Can anyone help me out here?

I reached out to the Pixel and Tonic support and pointed them to this question. I added, that I want to be able to create drafts for existing entries but also for new entries.
Here is the answer:

There a three endpoint you will need:
entries/save-entry
elements/save-draft
elements/apply-draft

The first is kind of obvious :)
The second is the one you would use to create/save the draft of an
entry, meaning, you'll need to pass it an elementId which is the id of
the entry you want to create a draft for.
The last one is the one you would use to apply the draft to the main
entry. This one will need a elementId and draftId.
Now, I'm sure you can see the difficulty with creating only a draft as
a draft requires an entry first.

Note, the needed param for the second and third action is elementId (not entryId as needed for the first action).
